# Where is the ledger supposed to attach to the rim joist?

Tags: deck, ledger, structure

If you look at the pic there's a gap right under the door way, about 5 inches deep and high. The rim joist of the house is halfway behind the brick and the other half is exposed right under the door.

Can I just fill in the gap with say a 6x6 post and secure that to the rim joist, then attach my ledger board to that and through the brick veneer? Would that be an acceptable method of securing the ledger or are there any other options? Otherwise, I am considering a free-standing deck.

[image]

Comment: Bolting a 6" member to the rim creates a high-stress cantilever situation. That's not a good approach.

Comment: It looks like a fairly new building. Have you asked the builder about the plan?

Comment: I've tried but haven't been called back, he's no longer in business.. It was his house he lost it.. It was a foreclosure so don't think he cares to help..

Comment: There were 4 concert supports spanning the whole 70 ft of the house but had to knock them down since they were not finished and starting cracking and falling apart.. I'm just trying to figure out what his plan was.. Only having four supports he would need a pretty decent beam to support 70 ft of deck.. And trying to figure out how to attach this to the house is beyond me.. Besides cutting out the brick where I need to attach..

Comment: "Concert supports"?

Comment: Sorry concrete block not concert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd get an engineer involved and design some steel plates to be bolted to the ends of your joists. I'd then use appropriately heavy 2x4 joist hangers on a half-height ledger. It would look something like this (profile view):

```
 ______________________________________________
|------------------------------------
|| *               *             *   |
||                                   |
||_______                            |
|______ |  *                     *   |
       ||                            |
       ||  *                     *   |
       ||____________________________|
       |_______________________________________
```

Comment: Never thought of that.. Be better than doing a free standing deck and have 14 holes in the ground and ruining the bottom entrance access.. I like it I appreciate the feed back I'm gonna look into that